# Cache Control in JSF

Tags: jsf, caching, jsf-2, facelets

I have many JSF pages which uses `<ui:composition>`. Say I have following pages

- `common.xhtml` (here define `head` and `body`. It is parent/main/top page of all pages)
- `p1.xhtml` (included in `common.xhtml` using `<ui:composition>`)
- `p2.xhtml` (included in `common.xhtml` using `<ui:composition>`)
- `p3.xhtml` (included in `common.xhtml` using `<ui:composition>` and I want to reload JF and css files when this page hits)

I go through [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers) link, but it will not gonna help me because I have to put the header in the `common.xhtml` (this will stop caching all JF and CSS files, and I donot want this.)

How can I reload js and css files **only** when `p3.xhtml` hits ?

**EDIT**

I added following in `common.xhtml`

```
<h:head>
   ....
   <ui:insert name="metaTags" />
</h:head>
```

I added following in `p3.xhtml`

```
<ui:define name="metaTags">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
</ui:define>
```

But still it didn't pick my updated js file.

Answer (score 3):

Based on @BalusC comment (thanks for the comment) I will totally rewrite my answer:

You don't need any Servlet, you can include your logic in any of the JSF lifecycle phases implementing a JSF phase listener. I have adapted the content [here](http://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2006/08/08/disable-browser-caching-in-jsf/) to your question.

You only have to implement a phase listener wich triggers before render phase and declare it inside the faces-config.xml file.

The declaration:

```
<lifecycle>
    <phase-listener id="nocache">com.company.package.CacheControlPhaseListener</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>
```

The phase listener code:

```
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseId;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseListener;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class CacheControlPhaseListener implements PhaseListener
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public PhaseId getPhaseId()
    {
        return PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event)
    {
        FacesContext facesContext = event.getFacesContext();
        if("/p3.xhtml".equals(facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestServletPath())){
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();
            response.addHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
            response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            // Stronger according to blog comment below that references HTTP spec
            response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
            response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate");
            // some date in the past
            response.addHeader("Expires", "Mon, 8 Aug 2006 10:00:00 GMT");
        }
    }
}
```

**The incorrect initial answer:**

You could write a `define` similar to this in `p3.xhtml`:

```
<ui:define name="nocache">
    <meta http-equiv=... />
    ...
</ui:define>
```

and write an `insert` in the head section of `common.xhtml`:

```
<ui:insert name="nocache" />*
```

Comment: You say in your question: "this will stop caching all JF and CSS files, and I donot want this..". Did you check it? I asumed you had chrcked the answer you cite in your question, dio you?

Comment: @BalusC is there any tag is JSF that can help me or I have to implement a servlet ?